# SQL Server Query Plan Hash Collision

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, database-internals, hashing

I'm wondering if anyone can shed light on a worry of mine that a `query_plan_hash` collision could cause a query to be executed as an entirely different query.

The hash is a 16 digit Hex that `sp_help sys.dm_exec_query_stats` says is a binary. Therefore it's only a 64 bit hash, and a collision seems very probable (considering SHA1 [160 bit] was just verified to have had collisions).

Would the `plan_hash` and the `query_plan_hash` both have to collide for this (query to be executed as an entirely different query) to happen?

I'm also curious if there is a setting somewhere in SQL Server that will allow us to change this hash to SHA2-512 (to reduce the possibility of a collision). Our data is very important.

I searched high and low via Google and Stack Exchange forums.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Neither `query_hash` nor `query_plan_hash` are used to look up query plans for execution, so the exact concern in the question does not arise.

The documentation for [`sys.dm_exec_query_stats`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189741.aspx) explains that:

- `query_hash` is provided to allow *users* to aggregate resource usage for  queries that differ only by literal values (ones that would parameterize to the same form).
- `query_plan_hash` is provided to allow *users* to calculate the cumulative cost of queries with similar execution plans.

---

Unsurprisingly, the SQL Server developers have gone to great lengths to ensure that cached plans are only reused when it is **safe** to do so. This goes well beyond the obvious requirement that the cached plan must match the 'query' exactly.

Briefly:

SQL Server has multiple plan cache stores, each implemented as a hash table. A *hash value* and *cache key* pair is used to connect a compiled plan with a particular 'query'.

The *hash value* is `(database_id * object_id) mod (hash table size)`. This determines the hash bucket in a particular cache store. The `object_id` is known metadata for objects like  procedures, functions, and triggers. For ad-hoc SQL, the `object_id` is a hash of the entire batch text.

The *collection of attributes* that must match for a cached plan to match a 'query' is known as the **cache key**. This is used to find and confirm an *exact match* within the hash bucket. Some (not all) cache key attributes can be found in the documentation for [sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189472.aspx).

Importantly, for ad-hoc SQL, the entire batch text is one of the cache key attributes.

---

More details can be found in [3.0 How Cache Lookups Work](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2007/01/10/3-0-how-cache-lookups-work/) (and other articles in the series) by the Microsoft SQL Programmability & API Development Team.